# what's the final output image in multistage build?

Tags: docker

Below is the dockerfile that creates an image:

```
FROM diamol/base AS build-stage                  
RUN echo 'Building...' > /build.txt             

FROM diamol/base AS test-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /build.txt /build.txt
RUN echo 'Testing...' >> /build.txt              

FROM diamol/base
COPY --from=test-stage /build.txt /build.txt
RUN echo 'Done...' >> /build.txt
```

and my understanding is, the final image consists layers of diamol/base and the layer created after the last RUN command as picture below shows:
[image]

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Multiply posted at https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/12268/23883 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram is correct, in that each step in the multistage build builds on top of `diamol/base`.
In each step, the `build.txt` file is copied across and modified. You can verify the contents of the file by running a container from the final image (e.g. `foo`):

```
$ docker build -t foo .
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint=cat foo build.txt
Building...
Testing...
Done...
```

Answer (score 0):

`RUN`, `COPY`, `ADD` create layers, so technically you have 3 layers:

- the initial `diamol/base` layer
- one layer on top, that contains the copied `build.txt`
- and the final layer in which you append done to the text file.

You can inspect the image yourself to check the layers that are created in the build process:

```
docker inspect <image-ID> --format '{{json .RootFS.Layers}}' | python -m json.tool
```

The two intermediate stages do create their own images that you can see in `docker image ls` with no name and tag `<none>:<none>`